# Tracing custom CUDA kernels with Nsight Systems

Tags: c++, cuda, profiling, nvidia, nsight

I work on library which is implemented in C++20 and CUDA 11. This library is called from Python via `ctypes` through a C API that just exchanges JSON strings. We compile it using Clang 11.

In order to profile the code I have added a lot of NVTX ranges to the C++ code. This works well for me with Nsight Systems, I can see the stack of ranges with their manually chosen names when use `nsys profile -t nvtx …` to gather data. This doesn't tell me anything about the GPU though. So I specify `nvtx,cuda,cublas,cudnn` in order to get more information.

But all I get is *one* of the many kernels. The output looks like this:

[image]

One can see the nice NVTX contexts, one can see the calls to the CUDA API (memcpy and the like). But there is only one kernel showing up, I have marked it with a red arrow.

We have a bunch of different kernels and launch them with the `<<<>>>` syntax right from the `.cu` files.

It feels like I am missing either a tracing flag for `nsys`, some compilation option for the CUDA code or some code annotations like NVTX for the kernel code. What do I have to do such that my custom kernels show up in the profile?

Comment: You are doing everything needed.  *A proof point for that is that you are witnessing a kernel execution in the profiler*.  Without a more complete example, I think it's unlikely anyone will be able to pinpoint the problem.  Some possibilities are 1. that the kernels you think should be called are not actually being called, 2. perhaps via profiler start and stop statements you have disabled profiling accidentally 3. You have some complex multi-process scenario and you are only profiling one of the processes.  I would seek to prove or disprove those theories in approximately that order.

Comment: Thank you, it turned out to be that the implicit stop with a non-terminating program isn't working well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue could have been that I have not properly stopped the data gathering and our program is an interactive server which one stops with a SIGINT. Perhaps the data was not properly stored after the interrupt.

I have added calls to the profiler API in the code such that I explicitly call `cudaProfilerStop()` after our main loop is done. I've done it with a small RAII wrapper such that it works even with SIGINT.

```cpp
#include <cuda_profiler_api.h>

class ProfilingRange {
 public:
  ProfilingRange() {
    cudaProfilerStart();
  }

  ~ProfilingRange() {
    cudaProfilerStop();
  }
};
```

On the `nsys profile` command line I specify `--capture-range=cudaProfilerApi` and it seems to work fine. Now a lot of kernels show up, and I can learn a lot more about the system.